# MySQL Setting a JOIN ON field valid or not? "JOIN ON a = b SET a = c"

Tags: php, mysql, join, out-of-memory

Can I update the same column I am using for a join? It seems like I can, but my script is crashing when I do.

Background: I have an old database that I am migrating. I am processing it through a ton of MySQL queries running in a PHP loop. The loop workers great, which each query taking 0.5 to 1 MB of memory to process. Until it hits this query and suddenly it takes 101% of whatever memory I have allocated to PHP:

```
UPDATE a.t1
  INNER JOIN t2
  ON t1.category = t2.oldcategory
SET t1.category = t2.newcategory
WHERE t1.category <> '';
```

When memory_limit was set to 128M the error thrown was:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted 
(tried to allocate 12288 bytes)
```

When I bumped the memory_limit to 256M the error is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted
(tried to allocate 32768 bytes)
```

But this very similar query runs just fine:

```
UPDATE a.t1
  INNER JOIN t2
  ON t1.category = t2.oldcategory
SET  t1.series = t2.series_term
WHERE t1.category <> '' AND t2.newcategory <> '';
```

PHP code by request:

```
$queries = array (
// dozens of MySQL queries here, like this:
["Count users",
"SELECT id from $s2.$usr;"
],
)

foreach ($queries as $query){
  $mtime = time();
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query[1]);
  $mem = number_format((memory_get_usage()/1024/10124),2);
  $mtime = time() - $mtime;
  $mtime = gmdate("i:s", $mtime);

  if ($result) {
    $rows = number_format(mysqli_affected_rows($link));
    echo "<tr><td>$mtime</td><td>$rows</td><td>$query[0] — $mem Mb</td></tr>";
  } else {
    $rows = mysqli_error($link);
    echo "<tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>".$query[0]."<br><span style='color:red;'>".$rows."</span></td></tr>";
  }
}
```

**Is there something illegal or recursive about using `SET` on the same column used for `ON`?**

UPDATE:

I just created two small test tables and successfully ran this query:

```
# works
UPDATE table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
SET t1.column1 = t2.column2
WHERE t1.column1 <> '';
```

UPDATE 2:

I edited the WHERE clause and now it runs correctly in .19 seconds using 0.04 Mb of memory:

```
UPDATE a.t1
  INNER JOIN t2
  ON t1.category = t2.oldcategory
SET t1.category = t2.newcategory
WHERE t1.category <> '' AND t1.category <> t2.newcategory;
```

Comment: Please show php code as well, you may see `memory_limit` set in `php.ini`

Comment: Instead of doing a update with the whole database, can't you set it in chunks for example for every 50,000 update instead of update queries at once.

Comment: Akshay Hegde, my PHP limit is set to 256M, raised from 128M after the first error.

Comment: Rahul I can try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can`t update same columns which are used in join statement.
Think about the logic.
It updates one row and it has to recheck the value again since it`s joined using same column. So this becomes endless recursion which will lead you to out-of memory exception.

Why don`t you first save ids which are needs to be updated and values in key value array.
Then run a loop and update separately?

```
SELECT t1.id,t2.newcategory from t1
  INNER JOIN t2
  ON t1.category = t2.oldcategory
```

run a `foreach` loop for the result list and update each row

```
foreach($queryResul as $row){
UPDATE t1  SET t1.category = $row->newcategory where t1.id = $row->id; }
```

Comment: Why would it need to recheck the value again? I'm presuming the order of operations does the JOIN ... ON first, making a big table, then crawls down the rows performing the SET. Is that incorrect?

Comment: I don't know what a key value array is. Can you propose code?

Comment: "Recheck" or Re-run the loop is to prevent endless recursion
check the updated answer

Comment: This code doesn't seem complete, as there is only one "(" and three ")" and I don't know enough to correct it.

Comment: I`ve edited it again. sorry for syntax error. Idea is to get all ids and values which should be updated and update them with another query which loops for every id which should be updated

Answer (score 0):

<del>I think the following code will also work well!

**Here codes:**

    UPDATE a.t1
      INNER JOIN t2
      ON t1.category = t2.oldcategory
    # SET  t1.series = t2.series_term   ## with out SET
    WHERE t1.category  '' AND t2.newcategory  '';

 **AND t2.newcategory  ''** the more condition let it works.

I think it is more condition let it works because of more condition filter more data and let MySQL use lesser memory.</del>

---

sorry, just read your code, you can't set data on the join condition, you will in endless loop

Comment: But nothing is being SET in your code. I need to update t1.category with new values.

Comment: did u understand my answers? if you want to update t1.category, you should add more condition or increase memory_limit

Comment: I wrote that I already increased the limit. This query uses 101% of all memory no matter how large I set the limit. It used 257M when the very similar query after it used just 0.5M. And t2.newcategory has no empty rows.

Comment: "you can't set data on the join condition, you will in endless loop" So how do I update this data? Maybe first copy it to a temp column?

Comment: sorry, I've updated my answer! I didn't read your code very carefully

Comment: maybe copy to a temp table can let it works, but in my mind, you should change your tables relationship or add other columns to keep relationship

Comment: my advice is to pay more attention to database design.